# Why *str1 and *(&str1), with str being the name of a char array in C, do not evaluate to the same result?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-address

The code is simple but I just do not understand how it works. All three variables seem to be stored at the same address, maybe with str1 being just an alias for str[0], but when I try to dereference them, I get different results.

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        char str1[] = "Hello";

        printf("<========Addresses: =======> \n");
        printf("%d\n", &str1[0]);
        printf("%d\n", &str1);
        printf("%d\n", str1);

        printf("<========Values stored at the address(?!)=======> \n");
        printf("%d\n", *(&str1[0]));
        printf("%d\n", *(&str1));
        printf("%d\n", *str1);
        return 0;
    }
```

And this is what it prints.

> <========Addresses: =======>
>
> 6356458
>
> 6356458
>
> 6356458
>
> <========Values> stored at the address=======>
>
> 72
>
> 6356458
>
> 72

Comment: `%d` is not the proper format for printing addresses; use `%p` instead.

Comment: @StephanLechner You're right, but I wanted to see if the same value appears on the bottom side too. In this case %p would make if harder to read and compare the values and since I'm just trying to understand how this works I used %d.

Comment: Use `%p` for the top bunch and `%lx` for the bottom and this may make it more clear. If you do that, you'll notice that the middle _value_ prints the same value as the _address_ of `str1`. Thus, `*(&str1)` is adding an extra level of indirection relative to the others [which produce the correct hex value of `48`, which is `'H'`]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First lets go through the pointers you have:

1. `&str1[0]`: This is a pointer to the first element of the array. Its type is `char *`.
2. `&str1`: This is a pointer to the array itself. Its type is `char (*)[6]` (don't forget that strings in C are null-terminated, and that terminator needs space too).
3. `str1`: This will *decay* to a pointer to the first element of the array, and is exactly equal to `&str1[0]` (i.e. the first one).

Now that we know that the first and third pointer is a pointer to a single element in the array (the first one at index `0`) it's easy to see what happens when we dereference it with the unary `*` operator: We get the value of the element the pointer is pointing to. Which is the letter `'H'`, which have the value `72` in [ASCII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) encoding.

To explain the result of `*(&str1)` is actually rather simple, as we can remove the parentheses and get `*&str1`. Then its easy to see that the dereference and address-of operators will cancel each other out, leaving us with `str1`. And `str1` is, as explained above, is equal to `&str1[0]`, i.e. a pointer to the first element in the array.